# Why include include the entire `lambda` expression in list comprehension?

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

In his [writeup](https://www.toptal.com/python/top-10-mistakes-that-python-programmers-make) on Python programming mistakes, Martin Chikilian includes the following to illustrate misconceptions regarding variable lifetimes inside closures:

```
def create_multipliers():
    return [lambda x: i * x for i in range(5)]

for multiplier in create_multipliers():
    print(multiplier(2))
```

The output is understandably surprising to some as `i` maintains its final value (4) in the closure between calls to `multiplier`. Martin includes a hack to get the desired output (please see his article for details).

What I'm wondering about is what is being accomplished by including the entire `lambda` in the list comprehension? Is it a common idiom in some field such as scientific computing? Because, to me, the following is much easier to understand:

```
def create_multiplier():
    return lambda x: [i * x for i in range(5)]

multiplier = create_multiplier()
print(multiplier(2))
```

Output:
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]

The output from the 2nd version roughly matches that listed as desirable by Martin. So what's going on here?

Comment: check SO python canonical: https://sopython.com/canon/30/why-do-my-lambda-functions-or-nested-functions-created-in-a-loop-all-use-the-las/

Comment: also python faq: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result

Answer (score 1):

They accomplish different things. The former returns a list of lambas that return numbers and the latter returns a lambda that returns a list of numbers. You can imagine different use cases for each.